# Framework7 app.dialog.confirm не работает на роутерных страницах

Tags: javascript, framework7

Начал работать с Framework7, столкнулся с проблемой. Если по клику вызвать `app.dialog.confirm('Подтверждаете?', function () {...});`
На главной странице все работает, а вот если перейти на роутерную страницу (по маршруту вызывается html страница) и там вызвать по клику, то ничего не происходит, зато при возращение на главную всплывает это диалоговое окно, сколько нажал столько раз и всплывает. Роутер настроен как в описании. Может кто подскажет?